# MPAndroid Chart , how do i format values on chart from floats to ints, interface is depricated

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

[image]

Hello , I want to format the values from the Line Chart , from the current floats into ints, I found that the library specifies the usage of the ValueFormatter interface , [link to git repo of the library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) but it is deprecated so i cannot use it anymore , any ideas how I could do it? Thanks

This is how it should have looked I suppose:

```
dataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return super.getFormattedValue(value, axis);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: You have to actually do some formatting in your formatter. Like "return String.valueOf((int) value);"

Comment: But I cannot use the code because it is deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getFormattedValue(float value)` instead of `getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis)` either on `LineDataSet` or `LineData` like below:

```
dataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return String.valueOf((int)value);
    }
});
```

I have tested on **v3.1.0**